# Howcome a string type variable is considered as boolean in Python?

Tags: python, string, boolean, conditional-statements

In the code below:

```
def modify_note(self):
    id = input("Enter a note id: ")
    memo = input("Enter a memo: ")
    tags = input("Enter tags: ")
    if memo:
       self.notebook.modify_memo(id, memo)
    if tags:
       self.notebook.modify_tags(id, tags)
```

`memo` and `tags` are string type variables. How can you write them after if, does python regard them as boolean here?

Comment: Is this Python 3.x?  `input()` has a different meaning in 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Just a note: unless you're using python 3, careful with input()! It's not the same as raw_input, as it evaluates whatever input you type in, equivalent to eval(raw_input())!

Comment: yes it is python 3.x.  what happened to raw_input in python 3?

Comment: "what happened to raw_input in python 3?"  That's an unrelated question.  First, search stack overflow.  Then read the Python 3 notes in Python's web site.  It's no secret.  Please read all available information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `if memo` and `if tags` statements are checking the [*truthiness*](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of the `memo` and `tags` variables.

> Any object can be tested for truth
>   value, for use in an `if` or `while`
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean
>   operations below. The following values
>   are considered false:
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()`
>     or `__len__()` method, when that
>     method returns the integer zero or
>     `bool` value `False`.
>
> All other values are considered true —
>   so objects of many types are always
>   true.

Comment: but in that code there is no way entering an empty string for tags and memo variables. which means they will always be true. right?

Comment: @alwbtc: If the user hits enter right away, you get an empty string, as the newline isn't included in the return value.

Answer (score 8):

Every object in Python has a [truth value](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).  Strings are `True` if they are non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on [Python's version of truthiness](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html)